# First script for automation of instagram , how to loop an else statment inside a for loop?

Tags: python, bots

Hi everyone first time poster long term reader.

my problem is I want an else statment to loop inside a for loop.

I want the else statment to loop until the if statment above it is met?

can anyone tell me where I am going wrong I have tried so many diffrent ways including while loops inside if statments cant get my head round this ?

### edit changed the code to a while loop not on prunes suggestion but cant escape the while loop

```
for url in results:
    webdriver.get(url)
    try:
        liked = webdriver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class=\"glyphsSpriteHeart__filled__24__red_5 u-__7\" and @aria-label=\"Unlike\"]")
        maxcount = 0   

        while not liked:
            sleep(1)
            webdriver.find_element_by_xpath('//span/button/span').click()
            numberoflikesgiven += 1
            maxcount += 1
            print'number of likes given : ',numberoflikesgiven
            sleep(2)
            webdriver.find_element_by_link_text('Next').click()

            if maxcount >= 10:
                print('max count reached .... moving on.')
                continue



        else:
            print ('picture has already been liked...')
            continue
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Comment: Your post appears to have a *lot* of code that is not part of your problem.  From what you've written, I think you need to review your educational materials on `if-else` statements and loops, to understand each as a building block.  You cannot "loop an else statement"; `else` is a clause of an `if` statement.  I *sounds* as if you want to repeat the body of your `else` clause until the condition in the `if` is met: this means that you need a `while` loop, not an `if-else`.  I suggest you draw a flow chart to help you identify just where your control-flow decisions should be made.

Comment: Hi Prune thanks for the quick reply I had tried a while loop as well please check edited code , 


the problem is with the while loop is that once it starts the loop it doesnt stop even if the like button has already been liked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you very clearly wrote an infinite loop:

```
while not liked:
    ... # no assignments to "liked"
```

You do not change the value of `liked` anywhere in the loop.  You do not `break` the loop.  Thus, you have an infinite loop.  You need to re-evaluate `liked` on each iteration.  A typical way to to this is to duplicate the evaluation at the bottom of the loop

```
        sleep(2)
        webdriver.find_element_by_link_text('Next').click()
        liked = webdriver.find_elements_by_xpath(
            "//span[@class=\"glyphsSpriteHeart__filled__24__red_5 u-__7\" \
            and @aria-label=\"Unlike\"]")
```

Also note that your `continue` does nothing, as it's at the bottom of the loop.  Just let your code reach the bottom naturally, and the while`will continue on its own.  If you intended to go to the next iteration of`for url in results`, then you need to`break`the`while` loop instead.

Comment: Hi sorry to be a pain but I re-evalutaed liked at the bottom of the while not loop and it still doesnt stop the loop

Comment: I'm pretty much out of things I can do until you follow the posting guidelines on explanation and code.  Besides the MCVE link, also see [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).